How to replace cartridge on Kohler Margaux faucet
The handle on the hot side of my widespread faucet is becoming harder to turn. I'd like to remove the handle cover and change out the cartridge, which I believe to be the reason of my problem.
However I'm not sure how to do that. I've seen many examples with Kohler where you untie the handle directly but on mine there is a setscrew in the back which I can't untie (and unsure if I need to).
Would you know how to remove the cover? PN# is K-16232-4-CP. Thank you!


